# The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

I am using ->
Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition,
,.Net Framework 4.5.2
,Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll version 3.0.0.0

In my local system not getting any issues but after pushing changes into release `pipeline` getting error like below.

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' does not exist
>   in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?

Did I missed anything

Comment: How did you reference 'Microsoft.ServiceBus'? Are you using Nuget or are you referencing a local file?

Comment: "after pushing changes into release pipe line" - so it's building and running fine for you locally, but your build or CI server isn't picking up the dependency correctly? What software is that? What is your release pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Add "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" package to your project:

[NuGet: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/3.0.0)

Configure your Azure DevOps Pipeline with a NuGet Restore:

[Azure DevOps: NuGet task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I have tried to install 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus'  with all versions from 3.0.0 to 4.1.1 through NuGet but not able to install.
For Ex getting error like :
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not install package 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 3.0.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.